# Colliding record error when connecting Google App Engine with my subdomain via A, AAAA, and CNAME records

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, google-app-engine

Our website is hosted with loopia at `example.com`, but we also have a webapp running on Google App Engine which we would like to run on `subdomain.example.com`.

We also have a couple of other subdomains running, but those are simply referred to via the IP address.

I have followed the steps at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update. The Domain Mappings consist of four `A`, four `AAAA` and one `CNAME` records.

When I try to add all of them to `example.com` (the documentation isn't clear if this should be the domain or subdomain), I get an error saying there are colliding records. When I try to add them to `subdomain.example.com`, I'm able to add either the `A`s and `AAAA`s or the `CNAME`, but not both, or I'll get a colliding record error again.

In both cases, `subdomain.example.com` just displays a Google backed 404 error, while `example.appspot.com` is working without problems.

This is very similar to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104248/dns-records-for-subdomain-with-google-app-engine-ambiguity), except that we're not using Google as our registrar.

How do I properly set up the DNS records so that the subdomain points to my webapp?

Answer (score 1):

You need only to use one of the following for the subdomain:

- `A` and `AAAA` records
- `CNAME` record

You can't use both at the same time for the same subdomain.  Because it is a subdomain, I'd recommend using the `CNAME` record.   Google likes to use dynamic IP addresses for its hosting.   If you use `A` records that specify an IP address, you might have to update them at some point.  If you use a `CNAME` pointing to Google's domain, Google will keep the IP address up to date for you.

You don't want to touch other DNS records other than for the subdomain.

- Don't edit the domain apex `@` records.  Those are for the bare domain and should usually point to the IP address that hosts your main `www` website.  (Note this particular record cannot be a `CNAME` and has to be an `A` record.)
- Don't edit the `www` records.  That will break your main site.
- Don't edit the records for your other subdomains, doing so would break them.